# How to remove the black background

Tags: c++, direct2d

I just started using Direct2D yesterday. I want to use the DrawLine function.

But when i call the function that draws the line, the line will appear but a black background also appears

[image: Diagonal green line on black background]

How can i get rid of the black background?

I tried to clear to NULL but that didn´t help.

I dont know what the problem is because i have nowhere declared a background.

Comment: This is the default when there's nothing else specified. What would you expect?  There's has to be *something*. You can call ID2D1RenderTarget::Clear https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-clear(constd2d1_color_f) method or show us some more code.

Comment: I use this to make a simple ESP for a game that displays me all NPCs. The code is:             https://hastebin.com/lipepehewe.php

Comment: As I said, pass a color to your Clear call if you want another background color, or draw something else before the DrawLine call.

Comment: Id did this g_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black, 0));  But the black background is still there. And i dont want to draw anything else because how should i play the game if there is a something drawn on the screen that is useless.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the Clear call

Comment: Yes. But then the lines get duplicated

Comment: What you want is an overlay, this is not that simple. Maybe try that: https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/programming-for-beginners/126003-transparent-overlay-direct2d.html